# Azure ShareFileClient UploadRangeAsync timeout or reset on large file

Tags: azure, timeout

Using `Azure.Storage.Files.Shares` v12.2.3.  I'm attempting to upload json files.  It appears that small files work without issue, but large files (~100MB) seem to "reset" after 90 seconds or so.  I wired into the `IProgress<long>` progressUpdate and I'm logging every 5%.  You can see it chugs along to 20% then it seems to reset.

Log excerpt:

```
[7/16/2020 11:48:37 PM] Uploading file: [2020-07-15.json]
[7/16/2020 11:48:38 PM] ... 0% [0/101494994]
[7/16/2020 11:48:58 PM] ... 5% [5111808/101494994]
[7/16/2020 11:49:19 PM] ... 10% [10223616/101494994]
[7/16/2020 11:49:40 PM] ... 15% [15335424/101494994]
[7/16/2020 11:50:00 PM] ... 20% [20316160/101494994]
[7/16/2020 11:50:19 PM] ... 0% [0/101494994]
[7/16/2020 11:50:39 PM] ... 5% [5111808/101494994]
```

```cs
public FileUploader(ILogger log)
{
    _log = log;
    string connectionString = Config.FileShareConnectionString;
    string shareName = "sharenamehere";
    _share = new ShareClient(connectionString, shareName);
    
    if (!_share.Exists())
    {
        _log.LogError($"File share not found: [{shareName}]");
        throw new ApplicationException("File share not found");
    }
}


public async Task UploadJsonFile(string fileName, object guts)
{
    // Get a reference to a directory and create it
    var directory = _share.GetDirectoryClient(Config.FileShareUploadDirName);
    await directory.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    
    // Get a reference to a file and upload it
    var file = directory.GetFileClient(fileName);
    if (await file.DeleteIfExistsAsync()) _log.LogInfo($"Deleted existing file [{fileName}]");
    
    _log.LogInfo($"Uploading file: [{fileName}]");
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(jw, guts);
                jw.Flush();
                sw.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;
                
                await file.CreateAsync(stream.Length);
                await file.UploadRangeAsync(new HttpRange(0, stream.Length), stream, progressHandler: progress);
            }
        }
        stream.Close();
    }
    _log.LogSuccess($"Uploaded file: [{fileName}]");
}
```

Any ideas?  I can't find anywhere to increase or set a timeout.  That's a hack anyway.  This is all running locally, by the way.  Probably much faster in the cloud as my internet has a super slow upload. But, I can upload files via the Azure portal just fine, so there's gotta be a setting somewhere to force `UploadRangeAsync` to just keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really an answer, but I logged an issue with the proper team and it is a timeout problem.  I went a different direction in the end, but maybe this will help someone else down the road:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/13545

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Letting others know about a bug that is keeping code from working is a legitimate answer. So are alternative solutions, if you want to share the other direction you went with. It can also be of use to include some of the core details of the bug here, so people that hit it might be able to understand why without having to read through an issue ticket that may become very long with stacktraces or eventually be archived or deleted, even though old versions or similar issues may still exist.